# Is it feasible to use video render with source reader technique?

Tags: c++, winapi, video, ms-media-foundation

I am writing a live streaming application using media foundation. I am using source reader technique. Is it possible to use video renderer with source reader technique?

If yes, please share your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to put some effort.

Video renderer can be used within [Media Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703988) pipeline, in which case it is managed by the pipeline and you don't need to bother with small details like sample delivery, seeking, flushing etc. As you preferred to use alternative higher level API [Source Reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940436), you no longer have video rendering as a part of it - you are supposed to manage video renderer, if you need it, yourself.

See also:

- [How to send IMFSample to EVR Media Sink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856180/how-to-send-imfsample-to-evr-media-sink)
- [Painting frames while media session is paused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623912/painting-frames-while-media-session-is-paused)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments.I have implemented the following features: live streaming, video recording , switching resolutions and retrieve current frame rate from renderer but I could not capture an image from photo stream using Media Session. So only I moved to source reader technique. In this technique, I'm facing frame loss for drawing video frame on window. Hence I planned to use video renderer inside source reader. I will explore the ideas from the first link and try to use in my application. I will get back to you if I face any issue. Thank you once again.